# How to prevent subviews from resizing when parent view is transforming in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, animation, autoresize

I have a parent view which is in form of a circle, and on that circle, there are 4 subviews, which are on the edges of the parent circle view.
On a button click, I am scaling in the parent circle using `CGAffineTransform`, and it start getting smaller, but along with that, the subviews are also scaling and getting smaller.

I can't seem to figure out, how can I control the subviews to prevent from scaling? I have tried setting `autoResizeSubviews` to false but it didn't work.I need to move the subviews along with the parent view while scaling.

I can scale up the subviews at the same time when I am scaling in the parent view, but that isn't the behaviour I want.What can be the possible solution here? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do those subviews really need to be added as subviews? How about having same parent view for all of these views and then scaling your circle view will not impact other views? Or is that subviews still need to move as circle is getting smaller but you wish to only preserve their size?

Comment: yes exactly, subviews need to move along with the parent view, and I want to preserve their size. Kindly Suggest any magic.

Comment: Please add this information in your question to make it clear for others while I do that...

Answer (score 0):

Since your subviews need to move but must not resize then only a part of transformation is applied to them. You need to either reverse the "unwanted" part of transformation or you need to extract only the wanted part of transformation and apply only that to subviews.

**Procedure 1: Reverse the "unwanted" part of transformation**

Since the position of your views is correct, they are just too small you can simply increase their size by scaling them.

```
let scale: CGFloat = ...
parentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
subviews.forEach { $0.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0/scale, y: 1.0/scale) }
```

**Procedure 2: Extract only change in position**

Since you don't want to apply same transform to your subviews you should rather add them to the same parent as your parent view. This way they will not change at all when you apply transform to your parent view.
To move them to correct position you may change centers of your subviews to the correct position. There are nice convenience methods for that...

Assuming that you have a list of your subviews and the original position for each of them. This position should be the `center` of each of your subviews currently. Then something like the following should correctly position these views when you change transformation on your parent view:

```
let subviews: [(view: UIView, originalPosition: CGPoint)] = ...
    
subviews.forEach { subview, originalCenter in
    let newLocation = parentView.convert(originalCenter, to: subview.superview)
    subview.center = newLocation
}
```

Comment: Okay, so first, sorry my question wasn't clear, and also, I forgot to tell you that my parent view is also rotating, so when the parent view will scale in while rotating, subviews must also rotate. By your approach, I am able to achieve the subviews to be of same size, but they are coming to the parent view centre in linear motion. Any way I can achieve rotation of subviews while keeping their size? That will be a huge favour man

Comment: @AbuBäkr is there a chance that you film a short video and post it somewhere and share a link. Preferably with both expected and current result. With this comments it is hard to tell what is what.

Comment: Okay I can try that. But Just Imagine that there is a parent circle, and around its edges, there are 4 more circles that are child views.. Now the parent circle is rotating and so are the child views. Now when Parent view is transformed, It will decrease in size while rotating, and the subviews will also decrease in size and will be in a rotary motion. I just want subviews to keep rotating and follow the movement of parent circle, but with the same size.

Comment: @AbuBäkr feels that the first solution should do all of that. What was your result with it and what would be the correct result?

Comment: I tried the first solution even before posting the question, but that was not fitting the UI situation. I tried your second approach, but it was not making the subviews rotate when parent view was scaling in, instead subviews were coming in linearly, so this solution didn't worked for me either. Thanks a lot for your time bro.For the time being, I am going with the small sized subviews